# How to add MySQL dependencies in react?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to add mysql dependencies in reactjs I am running

```
npm install mysql
```

but its giving me

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near 
'....tgz"},"engines":{"no'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06- 
22T01_58_05_155Z-debug.log
```

I uninstalled my npm and install it again and try to run `npm install --save react-router-dom` now its saying

```
npm install --save react-router-dom

npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...9a3f270fa24dbccdd5014'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-26T18_57_32_102Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Create a pastebin of `C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06- 
22T01_58_05_155Z-debug.log` and add that to your question as well

Comment: Whats your end goal? To retrieve data from a mysql DB? You may want to make a node service for that. Connecting to MySQL from a web client will be insecure as theres no way to hide user credentials.

Comment: @tarun i am not able to paste package.json in question because of characters limitations

Comment: @lex i am not able to add any dependency not only this one i just want to add dependency

Comment: I didn't notice that you want to make mysql call from the frontend. That is a big `NO` for any kind of an app, whether you care or not

Comment: if i try to add firebase or router dependency  its giving me the same error

Comment: Why do you want to connect directly to MySQL from the frontend? This is a bad idea on so many levels. As @Lex said, you should setup a node(or even rails) service, then have your React app interact with that service. This can be done pretty quickly these days.

Comment: have u try to clear npm cache and then try ?

Comment: @vivekmodi, can you host the `package.json` on github or pastebin and share the link?

Answer (score 1):

Your `package.json` file has a syntax error. For finding the error use JSON validator, for example, [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/). Also, every modern IDE has auto-validating features.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

**1. Clean your npm cache**

run this command in your project root folder:

> npm cache clean --force

**2. Delete package.lock.json**

**3. Delete node_modules folder**

run again

> npm install